Is the Bures metric equivalent to the Euclidean one?
Let $K=\mathbb R$ (reall numbers) or $K=\mathbb C$ (complex numbers). Define $\mathcal M_n$ to be the space of $n\times n$ matrices $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\le i,j\le n}$, with $a_{i,j}\in K$. Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the Euclidean norm on $\mathcal M_n$ and $d$ be its induced distance, i.e. $d(A,B):=\|A-B\|$.
Consider the subset $\mathcal S_n\subset \mathcal M_n$ of density matrices, i.e. $A\in \mathcal S_n$ iff $A$ is Hermitian, positive-definite and of unit trace. Denote by $\rho$ the Bures metric on $\mathcal S_n$, i.e. (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bures_metric for alternative metrics on $\mathcal S_n$)
$$\rho(A,B)^2:= 2\left(1- Trace\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}}\right)\right),\quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal S_n.$$
Does there exist $C>1$ such that
$$\frac1 C  \rho(A,B) \le d(A,B)\le C\rho(A,B) ,\quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal S_n?$$
PS : My attempt is to make use of the following fact : All the norms on $\mathcal M_n$ are equivalent. So a tractable idea is to construct a norm that induces $\rho$ when restricting in $\mathcal S_n$.

Is $C$ allowed to depend on $n$?

@GeraldEdgar Yes of course. Here $n$ is a fixed integer
